# How many solutions are there to $abc+def=ghi$, where $a,b,\ldots, h,i$ are distinct non-zero digits?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, permutations, integer-programming

I saw this problem posted by Google. Those posting in the comments found solutions using computer programming. I would like to know if there is an easier solution than trying every single combination.

[image: The Problem]

Comment: Programming a computer is quite an easy solution

Comment: I know, I did this in class on my Ti-84 calculator. I was wondering if it was possible to do it with only pen and paper had I not had my calculator with me.

Comment: Some tricks can be used to make it easier; i.e. not filling in the first digit of A or B with 9, since that would make C < A or C < B

Comment: You wouldn't have to try EVERY combination.  There are some you can eliminate as impossible, e.g. if $A>500$ and $B>500$ (to echo @Sim). That cuts down on the computing time somewhat.

Comment: I changed the title - hope it makes things clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a total of $168$ solutions. Given the number of solutions, the best way out seems to be to write a small program to do this for you. Below are the $168$ triplets without ordering. With ordering there are $2 \times 168 = 336$ such triplets.
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{First Number} & \text{Second number} & \text{Third number}\\
\hline\\
124 & 659 & 783 \\ 
125 & 739 & 864 \\ 
127 & 359 & 486 \\ 
127 & 368 & 495 \\ 
128 & 367 & 495 \\ 
128 & 439 & 567 \\ 
129 & 357 & 486 \\ 
129 & 438 & 567 \\ 
129 & 654 & 783 \\ 
129 & 735 & 864 \\ 
134 & 658 & 792 \\ 
135 & 729 & 864 \\ 
138 & 429 & 567 \\ 
138 & 654 & 792 \\ 
139 & 428 & 567 \\ 
139 & 725 & 864 \\ 
142 & 596 & 738 \\ 
142 & 695 & 837 \\ 
143 & 586 & 729 \\ 
145 & 692 & 837 \\ 
146 & 583 & 729 \\ 
146 & 592 & 738 \\ 
152 & 487 & 639 \\ 
152 & 784 & 936 \\ 
154 & 629 & 783 \\ 
154 & 638 & 792 \\ 
154 & 782 & 936 \\ 
157 & 329 & 486 \\ 
157 & 482 & 639 \\ 
158 & 634 & 792 \\ 
159 & 327 & 486 \\ 
159 & 624 & 783 \\ 
162 & 387 & 549 \\ 
162 & 783 & 945 \\ 
163 & 782 & 945 \\ 
167 & 328 & 495 \\ 
167 & 382 & 549 \\ 
168 & 327 & 495 \\ 
173 & 286 & 459 \\ 
173 & 295 & 468 \\ 
175 & 293 & 468 \\ 
176 & 283 & 459 \\ 
182 & 367 & 549 \\ 
182 & 394 & 576 \\ 
182 & 457 & 639 \\ 
182 & 493 & 675 \\ 
182 & 754 & 936 \\ 
182 & 763 & 945 \\ 
183 & 276 & 459 \\ 
183 & 492 & 675 \\ 
183 & 546 & 729 \\ 
183 & 762 & 945 \\ 
184 & 392 & 576 \\ 
184 & 752 & 936 \\ 
186 & 273 & 459 \\ 
186 & 543 & 729 \\ 
187 & 362 & 549 \\ 
187 & 452 & 639 \\ 
192 & 384 & 576 \\ 
192 & 483 & 675 \\ 
192 & 546 & 738 \\ 
192 & 645 & 837 \\ 
193 & 275 & 468 \\ 
193 & 482 & 675 \\ 
194 & 382 & 576 \\ 
195 & 273 & 468 \\ 
195 & 642 & 837 \\ 
196 & 542 & 738 \\ 
214 & 569 & 783 \\ 
214 & 659 & 873 \\ 
215 & 478 & 693 \\ 
215 & 748 & 963 \\ 
216 & 378 & 594 \\ 
216 & 738 & 954 \\ 
218 & 349 & 567 \\ 
218 & 376 & 594 \\ 
218 & 439 & 657 \\ 
218 & 475 & 693 \\ 
218 & 736 & 954 \\ 
218 & 745 & 963 \\ 
219 & 348 & 567 \\ 
219 & 438 & 657 \\ 
219 & 564 & 783 \\ 
219 & 654 & 873 \\ 
234 & 657 & 891 \\ 
235 & 746 & 981 \\ 
236 & 718 & 954 \\ 
236 & 745 & 981 \\ 
237 & 654 & 891 \\ 
238 & 419 & 657 \\ 
238 & 716 & 954 \\ 
239 & 418 & 657 \\ 
241 & 596 & 837 \\ 
243 & 576 & 819 \\ 
243 & 675 & 918 \\ 
245 & 673 & 918 \\ 
245 & 718 & 963 \\ 
245 & 736 & 981 \\ 
246 & 573 & 819 \\ 
246 & 591 & 837 \\ 
246 & 735 & 981 \\ 
248 & 319 & 567 \\ 
248 & 715 & 963 \\ 
249 & 318 & 567 \\ 
251 & 397 & 648 \\ 
254 & 619 & 873 \\ 
254 & 637 & 891 \\ 
257 & 391 & 648 \\ 
257 & 634 & 891 \\ 
259 & 614 & 873 \\ 
264 & 519 & 783 \\ 
269 & 514 & 783 \\ 
271 & 593 & 864 \\ 
271 & 683 & 954 \\ 
273 & 546 & 819 \\ 
273 & 591 & 864 \\ 
273 & 645 & 918 \\ 
273 & 681 & 954 \\ 
275 & 418 & 693 \\ 
275 & 643 & 918 \\ 
276 & 318 & 594 \\ 
276 & 543 & 819 \\ 
278 & 316 & 594 \\ 
278 & 415 & 693 \\ 
281 & 394 & 675 \\ 
281 & 673 & 954 \\ 
283 & 671 & 954 \\ 
284 & 391 & 675 \\ 
291 & 357 & 648 \\ 
291 & 384 & 675 \\ 
291 & 546 & 837 \\ 
291 & 573 & 864 \\ 
293 & 571 & 864 \\ 
294 & 381 & 675 \\ 
296 & 541 & 837 \\ 
297 & 351 & 648 \\ 
314 & 658 & 972 \\ 
317 & 529 & 846 \\ 
317 & 628 & 945 \\ 
318 & 627 & 945 \\ 
318 & 654 & 972 \\ 
319 & 527 & 846 \\ 
324 & 567 & 891 \\ 
324 & 657 & 981 \\ 
327 & 519 & 846 \\ 
327 & 564 & 891 \\ 
327 & 618 & 945 \\ 
327 & 654 & 981 \\ 
328 & 617 & 945 \\ 
329 & 517 & 846 \\ 
341 & 586 & 927 \\ 
342 & 576 & 918 \\ 
346 & 572 & 918 \\ 
346 & 581 & 927 \\ 
352 & 467 & 819 \\ 
354 & 618 & 972 \\ 
354 & 627 & 981 \\ 
357 & 462 & 819 \\ 
357 & 624 & 981 \\ 
358 & 614 & 972 \\ 
362 & 457 & 819 \\ 
364 & 527 & 891 \\ 
367 & 452 & 819 \\ 
367 & 524 & 891 \\ 
372 & 546 & 918 \\ 
376 & 542 & 918 \\ 
381 & 546 & 927 \\ 
386 & 541 & 927
\end{array}
And here is the MATLAB code. (Not the most efficient one. Took 12 seconds to run on my comp to produce this list.)

```
clear all;
clc;
t=0;
for i=1:9
    for j=1:9
        for k=1:9
            if (j~=i && k~=j && k~=i)
                t       =   t+1;
                A(t,1)  =   i;
                A(t,2)  =   j;
                A(t,3)  =   k;
                A(t,4)  =   100*i+10*j+k;
            end
        end
    end
end
count   =   0;
for k1=1:t
     for k2=1:t
         if(isempty(intersect(A(k1,1:3),A(k2,1:3))))
             if(A(k1,4)<A(k2,4))
                 c          =   A(k1,4) + A(k2,4);
                 rowindex   =   find(A(:,4)==c);
                 if (~isempty(rowindex))
                     if(isempty(intersect(A(k1,1:3),A(rowindex,1:3))))
                         if(isempty(intersect(A(k2,1:3),A(rowindex,1:3))))
                             count      =   count+1;
                             B(count,:) =   [A(k1,4),A(k2,4),A(rowindex,4)];
                         end
                     end
                 end
             end
         end
     end
end
```

Comment: Thank you!
I've never used MatLab before.  
I got the same number of solutions on my calculator program (10~ minutes to calculate)

Answer (score 3):

Here's some simple and very fast MAGMA code which only tests permutations of $1,\ldots,9$, as opposed to all $9^9$ triplets of $3$-digit combinations.  It ran in $3.042$ seconds on my computer.

```
Z := {@ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 @};
S := SymmetricGroup(9);
X := GSet(S,Z);
sol := [];
for s in S do
    Y := X^s;
    A := Y[1]*100 + Y[2]*10 + Y[3];
    B := Y[4]*100 + Y[5]*10 + Y[6];
    C := Y[7]*100 + Y[8]*10 + Y[9];
    if A + B eq C then
        Append(~sol,Y);
        end if;
    end for;
```

We can make this faster, actually, by noticing that $g+h+i$ must be exactly equal to $18$.  Furthermore, we can use a "carrying" method to rule out certain cases early.  The following runs in $1.982$ seconds.

```
Z := {@ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 @};
S := SymmetricGroup(9);
X := GSet(S,Z);
sol := [];
for s in S do
    Y := X^s;
    if Y[7] + Y[8] + Y[9] eq 18 then
        u := Y[3] + Y[6];
        if u mod 10 eq Y[9] then
            v := Floor(u/10) + Y[2] + Y[5];
            if v mod 10 eq Y[8] then
                w := Floor(v/10) + Y[1] + Y[4];
                if w eq Y[7] then
                    Append(~sol,Y);
                    end if;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end for;
```

Comment: Thanks! 
I've never heard of MAGMA before :o

Comment: Actually, my MATLAB code doesn't do all the $9^9$ permutations. It first stores the numbers with distinct digits. Anyway, yours check is orders faster. +1.

Comment: @user17762 Thanks! That sentence was a response not to your MATLAB code but to OP's request for code which "doesn't try every single combination."